# How do I tell a GUI application to open itself on a particular X11 display port?

Tags: gui, xorg, vncserver

I have a second X11 display port which is created by VNCServer on startup (vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800); and I would like to start a GUI-only application on this second display at startup also.

How can I do this?

(the application in question is PS3MediaServer FYI)

Answer (score 0):

Most X applications take a -display or --display argument.   Setting the DISPLAY environment variable supported by almost all X applications, since support for it is built into libX11's XOpenDisplay() API.

Comment: Thanks. PS3MediaServer appears to be a .jar executed by the JVM; how do I tell the JVM which X display to use?

Like so?

java blah.jar $DISPLAY=":1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a script and run it at startup:

```
#!/bin/sh
DISPLAY=:1.0 ; export DISPLAY
java ...
```